# Is my hiragana legible?

Tags: hiragana, handwriting

I have only recently started learning Japanese and was wondering if my handwriting is easy to read.

[image]

手伝ってくれてありがとうございます

Answer (score 2):

Your handwriting is almost perfect.

One note is that the right side of the "ほ" is not "ま."
The vertical line should not be extended upwards exceeding the horizontal line.

Comment: I would also point out the ふ. I mean, it's not that the way the OP wrote it is wrong, but looks to me a bit like cursive / 草書 compared to the rest. I mean it seems it is made with 3 strokes instead of 4.